# Leetcode: 733. Flood Fill

Tags: c#, depth-first-search

I am doing this problem and struggling so I find this answer:

```
public class Solution {
    public int[][] FloodFill(int[][] image, int sr, int sc, int color) {
        if(image[sr][sc] == color) return image;
        Fill(image,sr,sc,color,image[sr][sc]);
        return image;
    }
    
    private void Fill(int[][] image,int x, int y, int color, int oldColor) {
        if(x < 0 || y < 0 || x > image.Length - 1 || y > image[x].Length - 1 || image[x][y] == color || image[x][y] != oldColor) return;
        
        image[x][y] = color;
        
        Fill(image,x + 1,y,color,oldColor);
        Fill(image,x - 1,y,color,oldColor);
        Fill(image,x,y + 1,color,oldColor);
        Fill(image,x,y - 1,color,oldColor);
    }
}
```

I understand everything now, except for this part:

```
y > image[x].Length - 1
```

What exactly does that mean? I get the boundaries of x > image.Length - 1, but this one confuses me.

I am assuming that it means the boundaries of the xth column, but I would love clarification on this.

Comment: If you fail this challenge, beware that row-major order is a typical way to arrange pixels in a bitmap when using arrays of arrays.  So it may very well be that you have to access the pixel at `image[y][x]`.  Be careful and double-check the question for specifications of the input array and its relationship to the x,y coordinates.  I can't help but notice that it says `sr, sc`  which suggests r=row and c=column, but you've relabelled the variable names using x for rows and y for columns which is **highly atypical**.

Answer (score 2):

Your image seems to be stored as **an array of arrays**.  It's an **array of "rows"** actually.  Note that to access a pixel in the array you have to access `image[row][column]`.  First you access the array at `image[row]`, which is, itself, an array of all the pixels in that row, one for each column. Then you access the pixel at index `column` in that array.  i.e.:  `(image[row])[column]`.

My first complaint:  **You've used the variable names x and y unconventionally.**  :(

Typically we assign rows the coordinate `y` and columns the coordinate `x` so we would expect to have to access `image[y][x]` But you've done the opposite.

The code provides `sr` and `sc` which I assume the letters r=row and c=column.  This is corroborated by the quick-escape check:  `if(image[sr][sc] == color) return image;`  That `sr` is intended to be used in the major dimension (first index) and `sc` is intended to be used in the minor dimension (second index).

You have:

```
Fill(image,sr,sc,color,image[sr][sc]);
```

But you then have:

```
private void Fill(int[][] image,int x, int y, int color, int oldColor) {
```

So you're passing `x = sr` and `y = sc`.  That's very confusing / atypical / unconventional / backwards.  We usually use y for rows and x for columns.
However, it doesn't matter because you're actually using these variables consistently again by accessing `image[x][y]`.  Which is also backwards, but in this case two wrongs have made a right -- you've bucked convention by swapping labelling **and** order. Most of us have come to terms with the fact that, with an image that is an array of arrays, we have to write `image[y][x]`.  But you've just swapped the variable names.  It means you can write `image[x][y]`, which is appealing, but it's technically confusing for those of us that know better and stick to conventions.

#### The actual explanation

Setting aside your unconventional/backwards use of x and y,
it's checking `y` against "the length of the array representing the xth row" or "the number of columns in row x", which is `image[x].length`.

If y is in range, then `y < length`.  So we test the opposite to conclude that `y` is out of range.  Instead of checking `!(y < length)` it is logically equivalent to check `y >= length` or `y > length - 1`.  The last of these is the check you are using.  `y > image[x].length - 1`

The order of these tests is important:  if `x < 0` or `x > image.length - 1` Then the `x` index is out of bounds and it would be unsafe to even look at the xth row array to see what its length is (the xth row doesn't even exist in that case.)  So beware the order of the lazy `||` checks there.  We can be certain that `image[x]` exists because we've already checked `x` is in range in the left part of that expression.

Due to lazy evaluation of `||`, spelling it out explicitly,

```
x < 0 || y < 0 || x > image.Length - 1 // it's important this check comes first
|| y > image[x].Length - 1 // it's important this check comes after
```

Comment: Your relabelling of the variables with x for rows and y for columns actually tricked me into thinking you have a column-major image but you don't.  But I can see that the coordinates were passed in as `sr, sc`, which you labelled as `x, y` (atypical!).  Now I'm tempted to re-write this answer pointing out your labelling problem instead.  You *do* in fact have a row-major image.

Comment: I re-wrote my answer to address your unconventional swapping of `x` and `y`.